# How to add random src on audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have simple audio as background like this

```
<audio id="audioplayer" playsinline="" controls="" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" hidden="">
            <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
```

I want each time page is reloaded it should generate a new random number like this.

```
<audio id="audioplayer" playsinline="" controls="" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" hidden="">
            <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3?rand=0.8514959603294041" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

I have tried to add random math like this

```
<audio id="audioplayer" playsinline controls muted loop autoplay hidden>
            <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3?rand= + Math.random()"  type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

This is not working , what do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: You can't write JS code that way, you can add a custom <script> tag: `<script>document.querySelector('#audioplayer source').setAttribute('src', 'audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3?rand=' +  Math.random());</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` attribute in HTML does not process JavaScript. You need to find the `source` tag using for example JQuery to change the `src` attribute that way.

```js
$('#audioplayer source').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3?rand=' + Math.random());
});
```